# Are paused partial roms a good way to build into the full rom of an exercise?

Tags: push-ups, chest

I am trying to get myself to be able to do a full diamond push up. For that, I started do the partial rom I can, and holding it at the maximum rom I can go down, and then pushing myself.

Would this be a good way to reach full rom eventually, or would it just be better to keep doing push ups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. That is a good way to strengthen an exercise. The key is to go a little bit lower every time you do the exercise. So if you currently only go half-way, then go half-way + 1 inch the following workout that you do it. If you are unable to add extra length to your ROM for that workout, then you can add an extra rep or extra set to create more stimulus for the next workout.

Another way to do it is to do a full, slow negative all the way down, and then skip the concentric and reset. So in this case, you'd start at the top and as slowly as you can, lower yourself down to the floor. Then get up and reset back to the top, then try again.  Try to go slower every time you do the workout.